# Override Laravel Login to use Crypt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am doing an import from an old database which stored the passwords in plain text. I know, brutal. Although I want to store the passwords so that they can decrypt them after and view them. (Clients request). I am storing the password as

```
$user->password = Crypt::encryptString($oldUser->Password);
```

If the user logs in they will need to use this new Crypt to check. I have this but it keeps throwing me errors

```
Auth/LoginController


public function login(Request $request)
     {
        $user =   User::where('username', $request->username)
                     ->where('password',Crypt::encryptString($request->password))
                     ->first();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/');
     }




Users Model:
class User extends Authenticatable
```

The error is:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in

Comment: It looks like your `User` query is not returning anything. Is there a valid user?

Comment: If the passwords are in plain text, why not just hash them properly for each user? If the client really want to be able to see the passwords as well, just add a column with "old_password" which you save a crypted version of the password (which you then delete when they're done with it). Then you won't need to modify Laravels auth in any way.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just didn't want someone who could've got access to database to view the plain text password. Although, I will do this approach.